# How do not send email if it empty with rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to not send emails if them empty.

Here is my mailer:

```
class UsersMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "\"Example\"<reports@example.com>"

  def report(emails)
    @users = User.where(created_at: (1.days.ago)..(Time.now))
    mail to: emails
  end
end
```

End here is a rake task for:

```
task :users_browser_mail => [:environment] do
   emails = %w{me@example.com}
   UsersBrowserMailer.report(emails).deliver
end
```

So if `@users` is `nil` the emails is still sending how i can avoid this?

Should i do something in my rake task like?:

```
if @users
  UsersBrowserMailer.report(emails).deliver
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the query into the rake task.

`@users` won't exist in the rake task, as it's an instance variable within the mailer.

```
task :users_browser_mail => [:environment] do
   emails = %w{me@example.com}
   users = User.where(created_at: (1.days.ago)..(Time.now))

   UsersBrowserMailer.report(emails, users).deliver unless users.blank?
end

class UsersMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "\"Example\"<reports@example.com>"

  def report(emails, users)
    @users = users
    mail to: emails
  end
end
```